# How can you separate the band structure of two materials in a heterostructure?

Tags: material-science

I have a heterostructure with two layers A and B. I have calculated the wave-function, and properties (bands and dos) of the AB heterostructure as well as the A and B materials separately by removing the other material from the optimized (by DFT) lattice. I have considered getting the bands for each and then taking the order based on the energy of each band however depending on your measured symmetry points the energy ordering can obviously change during band crossings etc. Is there a simple method to determine which orbital belongs to which layer in the heterostructure?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What DFT package are you using?

Comment: @Niall I am using CRYSTAL. The output for the band calculation typically gives the eigenvalues at each orbital.